# turn focus of page to a specific part on the body

Tags: javascript, html

In facebook fan page tab application I click tab button and like to go to the specific 
portion of the fan page content without pixel calculation.

For example to point the comment box.
for that purpose url http://www.facebook.com/pages/AAAA/4444444?sk=app_UUUU8&app_data=php 
and

```
<div id="php"><textarea name="a"></textarea></div>
```

is in body

but I would like to achieve that goal automatically using Javascript?

Comment: Why use JavaScript? `<a href="#php">...</a>` will do the job and work more consistently.

Answer (score 1):

will this do?

```
<a href="http://abc.com/5677#php">link</a>
```

You could always style the link as a button, if you must.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code on click of the button

```
window.location.href="#php";
```

You can go to any part of the body using the above code and providing the id of the content you wish to go....

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `<a href="link u want">Connect</a>` is enough to do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById("php").scrollIntoView()">Go</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1)).scrollIntoView()">Go</button>
```

is a javascript alternative to using the anchor